# Parsing UTC dates yields different times

Tags: typescript, date, validation, parsing

I am working on a date parser

```
const parseDate = (data: any): Date => {
    const isDate = (d: Date) => !isNaN(d.getDate());
    if (
      Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Date]' &&
      isDate(data)
    )
      return data
    else if (typeof data === 'string') {
      const date = new Date(data);
      if (isDate(date)) return date;
      else return `Not a date`
    } else return `Not a date`
}
```

In this simplified version, it checks if it's date and returns it or it returns an error string.

However, it fails to parse properly on UTC:

```
const oddDate = new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z").toUTCString()
const result = parseDate(oddDate)
expect(oddDate).toEqual(result)
```

Jest gives the error:

```
    Expected: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z
    Received: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

It seems that

```
new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z") !== new Date(new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z").toUTCString())
```

How should I parse UTC times then properly?

Comment: There is no `toUTCTime` function on the `Date` prototype...

Comment: @HereticMonkey fixed, should be toUTCString()

Comment: Does `.toUTCString()` give you millisecond resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing precision when you call `.toUTCString()` function on the `oddDate`.

Notice the missing milliseconds on `oddDateStr`, while they are still present on `oddDateIso` below:

[image]

**Update** `toISOString()` does not lose precision:

[image]

The [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) does lose the precision as per string format used (namely, `Www, dd Mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT`).

Comment: I suppose there is no way to parse without losing precision then?

Comment: @Marc Define "parse". When you do `new Date(someString)` or `Date.parse(someString)`, you parse it at this moment. The precision is not lost here. The precision was lost at the moment when `toUTCString()` was called. You could use some function that formats the value as UTC but preserces that milliseconds suffix (`Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00.00.00.000 GMT`).

Comment: @Marc see my update which shows that `toISOString()` does not result in precision loss.